# What is the best way to extract module name for a JarFile programmatically?

Tags: java, jar, java-9, java-module

I'm working on a launcher library for Java 9 which uses module layering. In order to add a module in the layer I need to pass the module name (as a String) to the parent's configuration. [`ModuleLayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) Javadoc has an example just in the end of the class documentation.

Now, instead of forwarding the burden of the user of my library to declare the module names, I would like to allow just passing the jar file location as a `String`, `URL`, `File`, or `JarFile`.

So my question, given a `JarFile` what would be the easiest way of extracting the module name programmatically; automatic or declared?

Comment: I'm hardly an expert but module layers sound a lot like what we use ClassLoader for now.  If you want a custom class loader, you have to implement it yourself.  If the built-in module loading classes don't work for you, I suspect you'll have to define your own.

Comment: @markspace i can't augment new jars to the module system otherwise. The launcher allows to download the files over a network (for updating etc.) which is not present at startup. Don't worry about complexity, it works like a charm if I know the module names in advence.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to know a module name except to have it published somewhere.  I think that's why the current Java 9 requires publishing module names.  Consider the case where a Jar needs a different version of a module than the most recent.  How will you detect that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way I could think of to get to know the names of the module present in a directory is via [`ModuleFinder.findAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#findAll--) method:

```
Path jarDirectory1, jarDirectory2;
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(jarDirectory1, jarDirectory2);
Set<ModuleReference> moduleReferences = finder.findAll();
Set<String> moduleNames =
            moduleReferences.stream().map(mRef -> mRef.descriptor().name()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

***Edit***:: One-liner for the above as suggested by Alan for a single module(automatic) from its jar could be :

```
String moduleName = ModuleFinder.of(path_to_jar)
                        .findAll().stream().findFirst()
                        .‌​map(ModuleReference:‌​:descriptor)
                        .map(Mod‌​uleDescriptor::name)‌​
                        .orElse(null);
```

---

Another way could be to make use of the [`ToolProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html) and tweak the output stream to be able to store just the module name from :

```
Optional<ToolProvider> jar = ToolProvider.findFirst("jar");
jar.get().run(
        System.out,
        System.err,
        "--describe-module",
        "--file",
        "path/to/the/jar/for/example/commons-lang3-3.6.jar"
);
```

Comment: Alternatively, this should do it: `String mn = ModuleFinder.of(path_to_jar).findAll().stream().findFirst().map(ModuleReference::descriptor).map(ModuleDescriptor::name).orElse(null);`